# Residue of two functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f,g$ functions analytic in $z_0$, with $z_0$ a zero of order one of $g$ and $f(z_{0})\neq 0$. Show that 
$$
\operatorname{Res}\Bigl(\frac{f}{g},z_0\Bigr)=\frac{f(z_{0})}{g'(z_{0})}
$$
My attemp... If $z_{0}$ is a zero of order one of $g$, then $g(z)=(z-z_{0})h(z)$, with $h(z)$ analytic and $h(z_{0})\neq 0$, then by analyticity of $g$ and $h$: $g'(z)=h(z)+(z-z_{0})h'(z)$. So, 
$$
\frac{f(z_{0})}{g'(z_{0})}=\frac{f(z_{0})}{h(z_{0})+0}=\lim_{z\to z_{0}}{(z-z_{0})\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}}
$$ 
But in the ultimate point I'm not sure

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102601/residue-formula-in-complex-analysis/1174415#1174415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach: if the limit
$$\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$
exists and is not zero, then $f(z)/g(z)$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z_0$, and the limit is the residue.  Noting that  $f(z_0)\ne0$, $g(z_0)=0$, $g'(z_0)\ne0$ and evaluating the limit by L'Hopital's Rule shows that the limit does exist and is what you want.

Comment: How can this approach different from mine?

Answer (score 1):

The function $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ has a pole of order $1$ then the residue is given by

> $$ \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}, $$

since $g(z_0)=0$.
**Note:**

> $$ g'(z_0) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

$g(z_0)=0$, $g'(z_0)\ne0$, and $f$ and $g$ are analytic.  Thus, $g(z) = g'(z_0)(z-z_0) +O((z-z_0)^2)$.  Then, we have

$$Res_{z=z_0}\left( \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right)=\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) \frac{f(z)}{g'(z_0)(z-z_0) +O((z-z_0)^2)}$$

$$=\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{f(z)}{g'(z_0) +O(z-z_0)}$$

$$=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$

which was to be shown!